vertex AI training is ignoring allocated time and not finishing autoML training
I am trying to run an autoML on a relatively small data set (100K rows, 20 cols) and allocating 3 hours (the recommended time is 1-3h). Since I am on a budget, it's important that it finishes on time.
However at the top of the hour not only is the model not finished training, which is strange in itself, but it is also ignoring the budget.
Why is this happening?

Did you receive any error messages? Early stopping enabled?
